# Getting columns from DataTable stored in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datatable

So I have a DataTable which uses:

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID = ?
```

You can understand that this will only retrieve one row as the ID is unique:

```
usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter user = new usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();

users.UsersDataTable userDataTable = user.getUserInfo(id);
```

I have then stored the DataTable into a session:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("userDT", userDataTable);
```

Now I am trying to figure out, how would I get a specific column from the userDT in the session? To be more clear the firstname column?

Answer (score 1):

First cast the session object as a datatable.

```
var tbl = ((DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["userDT"])
```

Then use it like a data table:

```
var col = tbl.Columns["firstName"];
```

Comment: Is it then stored into the session? and rather than using `Session["firstName"];` I should use `tbl.Columns["firstName"];` to extract?

Comment: @Samrikan No, firstname would not then be stored in the session.  You'd have to add it to the session specifically.  Additionally, you're only getting the column here.. not the value.  To get the value, you need to loop through rows and get the value from the firstname column.

Comment: @Samrikan If you are using ADO.NET, you might just want to consider doing an `ExecuteScalar` and returning the single firstname value instead of messing w/ this datatable business.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast Session object to users.UsersDataTable:
    users.UsersDataTable userDataTable = Session["userDT"] as users.UsersDataTable;

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
 DataView dv = new DataView((DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["userDT"]);
```

get the table just with column

```
 DataTable dt = dv.ToTable(true, "firstName");
```